# Mysql Relational Database duplicate with different keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, duplicates

I'm trying to correct a relational db for a month, but i cant find efficient solution.

Hier is my problem:
I have like 534 M rows Relational Db with lots of foreig keys(30).

I can handle normal duplicates with union...group by...havin count(*)=1 by inserting, but there are also duplciates with different keys.

***example:***

table 1

```
id | key1 |  value 
1  | 11   |  a1  
2  | 22   |  a1
```

table 2

```
key1 | value 
11   |  a2  
22   |  a2 

Foreign key table1(key1) references table2(key1)
```

I'm trying to find, remove duplicate , correct the parents.
I have tried 3 different ways,

**1: PHP Script,Arrays**

export tables (dump) --> array_unique, find duplicates, correct the parents array --> import tables

Its pretty fast, but need 80GB Memory, which could be problem in the future

**2: PHP Script,SQL Query**

exporrt tables(dump) --> find duplicates --> send queries to parent table

No need memory, but the tables are really big and 5 queries take 1 second, 50 M duplicates would take days, months, years

**3: ON DUPLICATE UPDATE KEY:** I added one column 'duplicate' to store duplicate keys and  I defined all columns except key as unique key,
insert.... on duplicate update concat(duplicate,';',VALUES(key)).

But some tables has more than 1 key and sometimes I should define 24 column as unique index and memory problem again

I hope I could explain my problem. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Could you not do version 1 in blocks?  Sort it first, again in blocks to save memory, a merge sort in the files and memory.  Remove duplicates, easy once in blocks, allowing for edge cases.  Then produce an import.

Comment: You right, actually I can reduce the memory use by sorting array and importing blocks, but php is not good by garbage collection (some stupid memory leaks by large files), I should try it, thanx

Comment: Can you clarify if this is something that you expect to be performing regularly, or whether it's a one-off? I'm assuming from your "might be a problem in future" comment that it might need repeating.

Comment: Yes, it needs repeating

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply create a unique key on column. Just use "Ignore" keyword it will remove the duplicate records.
So your query will be something like: 
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `testdb`.`table1` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `column1` (`column1` ASC) ;

Comment: I should fix keys in parent table, so I can not easly ignore them